# How can I disable the new history feature in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, interactive

Since upgrading to Python 3.4, all interactive commands are logged to `~/.python_history`. I don't want Python to create or write to this file.

Creating a symlink to `/dev/null` does not work, Python removes the file and recreates it. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#rlcompleter-config) suggests to delete the `sys.__interactivehook__`, but this also removes tab-completion. What should be done to disable writing this history file but still preserve tab-completion?

Additional details:

- Distro: Arch Linux x86_64
- [readline 6.3-3](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/readline&id=46fff8f14496f292e22f82f3402a75c5bcc059dd)
- [python 3.4.0-2](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/python&id=19a95910353e50edf44838b33c7f8e2dea8844bb)

Comment: Have you tried chowning it to root?

Comment: @goldilocks I do not consider that an acceptable solution, and neither is using `chattr`. I am looking for a single (user) configuration file or environment variable.

Comment: Okay, but you already know there is no such acceptable solution since you've looked at the documentation.

Comment: In fact, `chmod` is the solution suggested by python devs in [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue20886) from a few weeks ago, although there is also some mention of `~/.inputrc` there (there is no `man readline`, BTW, except for the library function).

Comment: @goldilocks Yes, I was about to link to that bug report. I don't know how to use `inputrc` though and `chmod` does not work for me either, the file gets modified anyway (Arch Linux). There exists an `info inputrc` page, but I am generally not so happy with reading info pages as they are difficult to navigate through.

Comment: I don't know much about `inputrc` usage either -- there's [a guide here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html) -- but my gut tells me you won't be able to target the python shell directly that way and pitrou is playing a smoke and mirrors shell game in that report to blow it off.  `chown` may be the closest you can get, since if python is run non-privileged it won't be able to circumvent it.

Comment: The trick we used to use to prevent creation of `core` files, before there was support for doing so in `ulimit`, was `mkdir ~/core`. Maybe `mkdir ~/.python_history` will work until the python maintainers provide a proper fix.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Good suggestion, unfortunately it does not work as Python 3.4 still removes the directory (changing permissions does not make a difference).

Comment: Can you add the version of `readline`, and the OS and distro you're running, to your question? I just compiled Python 3.4.0 from source on Centos 6.5 (readline 6.0.4), and python did not remove the `~/.python_history` directory I had made (and didn't create a history file). When exiting, it output the error message `Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory`. It's possible that different versions of `readline` are more aggressive at trying to write the history file.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Arch Linux has readline 6.3, it must be Python's implementation then. bash 4.3 does not delete `.bash_history` if it is a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent Python from writing `~/.python_history`, [disable the hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#rlcompleter-config) that activates this functionality:

```
import sys
# Disable history (...but also auto-completion :/ )
if hasattr(sys, '__interactivehook__'):
    del sys.__interactivehook__
```

If you would like to enable tab-completion and disable the history feature, you can adapt the [`site.enablerlcompleter`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/site.py#l376) code. Write the following code to `~/.pythonrc` and set `export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc` in your shell to enable it.

```
import sys
def register_readline_completion():
    # rlcompleter must be loaded for Python-specific completion
    try: import readline, rlcompleter
    except ImportError: return
    # Enable tab-completion
    readline_doc = getattr(readline, '__doc__', '')
    if readline_doc is not None and 'libedit' in readline_doc:
        readline.parse_and_bind('bind ^I rl_complete')
    else:
        readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
sys.__interactivehook__ = register_readline_completion
```

Comment: This does the job. I wonder why they're not using `${XDG_STATE_HOME}/python/history` for this purpose, though.

Comment: Any idea where the history filename path (`~/.python_history`) is stored?

Comment: See the `site.enablerlcompleter` link in my answer. It is hard-coded there. On Python 3.10.2 on Arch Linux, it can be found on line 475 of `/usr/lib/python3.10/site.py`.

Answer (score 13):

Another ~/.pythonrc solution:

```
import readline
readline.write_history_file = lambda *args: None
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't upvoted more.  This is simple and directly suppresses *writing* the history file instead of disabling history entirely.

Comment: This was the only fix that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: So I get to replace one turd in my home directory with another

Answer (score 9):

As of Python 3.6, you can use [readline.set_auto_history](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#readline.set_auto_history) to disable this:

```
import readline
readline.set_auto_history(False)
```

Comment: That's good for the Python shell, but beware: it doesn't seem to work in ipython.

Comment: This disables history entirely.  Personally I'm fine with history being preserved in my interpreter session, but I just don't want my history written to disk and preserved across sessions.

Comment: Doesn't work. This doesn't stop the file being saved, and instead it breaks the history during the session. In any case, Python silently turns the "feature" back on next time you run it.

Comment: This works for me, and can be applied to every session with an alias. For example: `alias python='python -i -c "import readline; readline.set_auto_history(False)"`.

Comment: For those saying this doesn't work, it's supposed to be added to `~/.pythonrc` so it runs before every session.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me.

Creating `~/.pythonrc` file:

```
import os
import atexit
import readline

readline_history_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.python_history')
try:
    readline.read_history_file(readline_history_file)
except IOError:
    pass

readline.set_history_length(0)
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, readline_history_file)
```

Then export it:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc
```

Comment: This seems to *enable* writing a history file instead of *disabling* it if I am not mistaken? Unless [`set_history_length`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#readline.set_history_length) does something magical? Tab-completion is done for functions, not history.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: yes, it make history size equal zero so nothing is written to history file. Oh, I though you want to preserve command between sessions.

Comment: This still causes `~/.python_history` to be written (verified with `PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc strace -e file,write -o /tmp/st python`). I start to think that there is no way to disable this, but keep tab-completion without duplicating code from `/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py`.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to really disable it.

Answer (score 2):

My current solution (for recent enough versions of Python 3) prevents default use of ~/.python_history but leaves the possibility of explicit writing of the history to a given file (using readline.write_history_file(filename) or readline.append_history_file(...)) is to have the following in one's PYTHONSTARTUP file:

```
import readline
import time

readline.add_history("# " + time.asctime()) # prevent default use of ~/.python_history
readline.set_history_length(-1) # unlimited
```

It has the pleasant (for me) side effect labeling any explicitly written history with the startup time of the interpreter. It works because of the fix for [bug 5845](http://bugs.python.org/issue5845#msg198636) which can be seen [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/687dd81cee3b).

Comment: History length of `-1` (i.e. unlimited) is already the default (verify with `readline.get_history_length()`), so that line is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Until it's fixed in some way in Python itself you can do this on UNIX systems:

```
rm ~/.python-history
mkdir ~/.python-history
sudo chattr +i ~/.python-history || sudo chflags simmutable ~/.python-history
```

After that you will be getting

> Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
>
> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory

every time you terminate a python shell. Exit status will still be `0`.

Notice that if you leave it as file you need to create and make immutable another file, `~/.python_history`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a file and set `PYTHONSTARTUP` to it (or call the file `sitecustomize.py` and make it accessible from the `PYTHONPATH`)

```
import readline
import atexit
import sys

sys.__interactivehook__()
atexit.unregister(readline.write_history_file)
```

This way you'll still have access to tab-completion and previous history, but the commands you enter won't be added to the history file.

Comment: This does not seem to work (Python 3.5.1 on Arch Linux), the history file is still written on exit even through the `PYTHONSTARTUP` script is indeed executed.

Comment: I just tested it on my Arch Linux vm, and it works fine: https://gist.github.com/berdario/640b3ab00b128fdf3338

Answer (score 0):

Here's my method (which turned out to be basically a more reliable and pythonic version of berdario's method). It only disables writing to `.python_history`, but not reading from it if it exists, or appending new lines to the current instance's history. I recommend saving it as `site-packages/sitecustomize.py`, because [`site` is the module that both writes to `.python_history` and imports `sitecustomize` if it exists](//docs.python.org/3/library/site.html?highlight=sitecustomize%20python_history#index-3), although naming it something else and pointing to it with `PYTHONSTARTUP` works too.

```
import sys
oldhook = getattr(sys, '__interactivehook__', None)
if oldhook:
    def newhook():
        import readline, atexit
        oldhook()
        atexit.unregister(readline.write_history_file)
    sys.__interactivehook__ = newhook
```

update: what i did for 3.7, specific to my system, not pep8:

```
import rlcompleter,readline as r,sys
def f():r.parse_and_bind('tab:complete');r.read_init_file()
sys.__interactivehook__=f
```

Comment: Python 3.7.3. Not working. History still logged.