# Change location of `~/.python_history`

Tags: python, python3

I want to keep the functionality, but change the location of `~/.python_history` to `$XDG_DATA_HOME/python/python_history`.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297834/282466) gave me the following idea:
I could create `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/python/pythonrc` and point `$PYTHONSTARTUP` to it.
In there I want to replace the functions `readline.read_history_file`, `readline.write_history_file` and `readline.append_history_file`.

Is there way to replace these functions with themselves, containing a custom `filename` argument?

If not, do you have another idea how to approach this?

Comment: Here is an attempt of a more graceful solution: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97007. Consider voting for it.

Comment: For those who don't need python history at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63653039/10178283

Answer (score 4):

Like you & ctrl-alt-delor, I sought the mythical clean home directory. The call to `readline.write_history_file` is registered to run on exit in `site.py` (on my arch system, at `/usr/lib/python3.9/site.py`):

```
if readline.get_current_history_length() == 0:
    # If no history was loaded, default to .python_history.
    # The guard is necessary to avoid doubling history size at
    # each interpreter exit when readline was already configured
    # through a PYTHONSTARTUP hook, see:
    # http://bugs.python.org/issue5845#msg198636
    history = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),
                           '.python_history')
    try:
        readline.read_history_file(history)
    except OSError:
        pass

    def write_history():
        try:
            readline.write_history_file(history)
        except OSError:
            # bpo-19891, bpo-41193: Home directory does not exist
            # or is not writable, or the filesystem is read-only.
            pass

    atexit.register(write_history)
```

You can duplicate this in your PYTHONSTARUP but with a custom location for the python history. Here's mine (but if you like I'm sure you could used environment substitution to use the appropriate XDG directory.:

```
import os
import atexit
import readline

history = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.cache/python_history')
try:
    readline.read_history_file(history)
except OSError:
    pass

def write_history():
    try:
        readline.write_history_file(history)
    except OSError:
        pass

atexit.register(write_history)
```

You *could* overwrite the write_history_file function, but it's very hacky (you need it to ignore the argument it's given in lieu of your custom one), so I think this is the best solution. If this doesn't work, try creating a dummy entry in your custom python history file, so the history length is greater than 0.

Comment: For the record, the `site.py` snippet shown for Python 3.9 is in CPython since 2013, has been mostly unchanged since then, and is still there for Python 3.11, so it seems safe to use a solution based on its behavior: https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/main/Lib/site.py#L467-L488

Comment: It can also be improved to create the needed dummy entry for you on first run when there's no history file yet: `if readline.get_current_history_length() == 0: readline.add_history("# history created")`, as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529866/4919)

Answer (score 2):

The one [`xdg-ninja`](https://github.com/b3nj5m1n/xdg-ninja) uses (pasting here for convenience):

Export environment variable:

```bash
export PYTHONSTARTUP="/etc/python/pythonrc"
```

Create `/etc/python/pythonrc`:

```py
import os
import atexit
import readline
from pathlib import Path

if readline.get_current_history_length() == 0:
    state_home = os.environ.get("XDG_STATE_HOME")
    if state_home is None:
        state_home = Path.home() / ".local" / "state"
    else:
        state_home = Path(state_home)

    history_path = state_home / "python_history"
    if history_path.is_dir():
        raise OSError(f"'{history_path}' cannot be a directory")

    history = str(history_path)

    try:
        readline.read_history_file(history)
    except OSError:  # Non existent
        pass

    def write_history():
        try:
            readline.write_history_file(history)
        except OSError:
            pass

    atexit.register(write_history)
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers here *prevent* `~/.python_history` from being created / written to.

`cpython` registers an `__interactivehook__` for the function `register_readline` here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/site.py#L485

This function sets up interpreter tab-completion, as well as a hook to write the history to `~/.python_history` when the interpreter exits. We can delete this hook to prevent `~/.python_history` from being written. We can then set up tab completion manually and register our own history writing hook.

Place the following code in your `$PYTHONSTARTUP` file:

```py
try:
    import atexit
    import os
    import sys
    from pathlib import Path
    import readline
except ImportError as e:
    print(f"Couldn't load module. {e}")
    sys.exit(1)


################
# TAB COMPLETION #
##################

try:
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
except ImportError:
    pass


### XDG Compliant History File
# See https://gist.github.com/viliampucik/8713b09ff7e4d984b29bfcd7804dc1f4?permalink_comment_id=4582040#gistcomment-4582040

# Destroy default history file writing hook (and also tab completion, which is why we manually added it above)
if hasattr(sys, '__interactivehook__'):
    del sys.__interactivehook__


histfile = Path(os.getenv("XDG_CACHE_HOME", Path.home() / ".cache")) / "python_history"
try:
    histfile.touch(exist_ok=True)
except FileNotFoundError: # Probably the parent directory doesn't exist
    histfile.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

readline.read_history_file(histfile)
# Don't store an obscene amount of history
readline.set_history_length(5000)
# Write to history file on exit
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, histfile)
```

Run `$ mv ~/.python_history $XDG_CACHE_HOME/python_history` and then run `$ python3` and enter a command. You should expect that `~/.python_history` was not created, and `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/python_history` contains your updated history.

Answer (score 2):

This will be possible in Python 3.13 with the merge of [PR 13208](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13208). It adds an environment variable `PYTHON_HISTORY` that can be used to customize the history file location.

```
export PYTHON_HISTORY=~/.local/share/python/history
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on this, inspired by [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675631/4919) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529866/4919):

```
# Enable custom ~/.python_history location on Python interactive console
# Set PYTHONSTARTUP to this file on ~/.profile or similar for this to work
# https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#example
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/site.py @ enablerlcompleter()
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675631/4919

import atexit
import os
import readline
import time


def write_history(path):
    import os
    import readline
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), mode=0o700, exist_ok=True)
        readline.write_history_file(path)
    except OSError:
        pass


history = os.path.join(os.environ.get('XDG_CACHE_HOME') or
                       os.path.expanduser('~/.cache'),
                       'python_history')
try:
    readline.read_history_file(history)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

# Prevents creation of default history if custom is empty
if readline.get_current_history_length() == 0:
    readline.add_history(f'# History created at {time.asctime()}')

atexit.register(write_history, history)
del (atexit, os, readline, time, history, write_history)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoyance of lots of files in my home directory. This is what I did.

- Create a directory `~/+Files`.
- Move all of my(not the annoying config files) files to this new directory.
- Configure interactive shell, and dolphin to start in this new directory.
- Create a directory for config files `~/+Files/config`
- Move config files to this new directory, and sym-link to them.

Now my home directory contains only sym-links and `+Files` directory.
From time-to-time I then inspect my home directory for cruft that has turned up. And decide what to do with it: move to config, remove, …

Comment: I am wondering if the XGD thing that you mention is better. But my ideas is a workaround for staff not supporting it.

Comment: XGD basedir implemented and understood has only upsides. Unfortunately many applications still fail to comply, but it gets better.
If you want the old clutter back, you can always set the XDG dirs into your HOME, have fun ^^